# Use akka to stream contents of streaming file as a HttpResponse

Tags: java, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

I am reading parts of large file via a Java FileInputStream and would like to stream it's content back to the client (in the form of an akka HttpResponse). I am wondering if this is possible, and how I would do this?

From my research, EntityStreamingSupport can be used but only supports json or csv data. I will be streaming raw data from the file, which will not be in the form of json or csv.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use akka-http and Scala you may use `getFromFile` to stream the entire binary file from a `path` to the `HttpResponse` like this:

```
path("download") {
  get {
      entity(as[FileHandle]) { fileHandle: FileHandle =>
      println(s"Server received download request for: ${fileHandle.fileName}")
      getFromFile(new File(fileHandle.absolutePath), MediaTypes.`application/octet-stream`)
      }
    }
 }
```

Taken from this file upload/download roundtrip akka-http example:
https://github.com/pbernet/akka_streams_tutorial/blob/f246bc061a8f5a1ed9f79cce3f4c52c3c9e1b57a/src/main/scala/akkahttp/HttpFileEcho.scala#L52

Streaming the entire file eliminates the need for "manual chunking", thus the example above will run with limited heap size.

However, if needed manual chunking could be done like this:

```
  val fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileHandle.absolutePath)
  val chunked: Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = akka.stream.scaladsl.StreamConverters
    .fromInputStream(() => fileInputStream, chunkSize = 10 * 1024)
      chunked.map(each => println(each)).runWith(Sink.ignore)
```

Comment: Thank  you for your example but unfortunately `getFromFile` won't work for me as I need to be able to stream  parts of a file. My understanding is that `getFromFile` will stream the entire file. I have updated my question to clarify that I will be streaming parts of a file.